# R function to merge values from 480 Data frames into one vector

Tags: r

I am trying to merge values from 480 data frames that are being generated through my forloops. I am getting one value each time. So each DF has one value. I want to generate a vector/list which holds all those 480 values. I am not understanding how to assign variables for nested loop iterations. Please check my code and let me know how I can do that. The code pasted below is giving me 480 dataframes.

[R Code: ```{r}
for(year in 2005:2020)
{ YearWiseList = team_v_team %>%
filter(season==year)
for(i in 1:nrow(YearWiseList) )
{
YearWiseList[i,] %>% gather("opponent","score",3:32) %>% select(!(margin)) %>% mutate(margin = YearWiseList$margin) %>% separate(col=score,into=c('win','loss'),sep='-') %>% mutate(sum=as.numeric(win)+as.numeric(loss)) %>% mutate(opp=margin * sum) %>% select(season,bb_ref_team_name,opp,sum) %>% mutate(oppmargin = sum(opp,na.rm=TRUE) / sum(sum,na.rm=TRUE)) %>% distinct(season,bb_ref_team_name,oppmargin) %>% print()
}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3RD6.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We could do the following:

1. clean your global environment.
2. Create your 480 dataframes
3. get them from the global environment
4. apply rbind to save all in a list
5. alternatively use `unlist()` to save in a named vector

Here is an example:

```
mtcars1 <- as.data.frame(mtcars[1,1])
mtcars2 <- as.data.frame(mtcars[3,1])
mtcarsn <- as.data.frame(mtcars[10,1])

dataframe <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

lapply(dataframe, rbind)
```

```
$mtcars1
  mtcars[1, 1]
1           21

$mtcars2
  mtcars[3, 1]
1         22.8

$mtcarsn
  mtcars[10, 1]
1          19.2
```

Comment: I could do that. but how do I save the 480 DFs into global environment. If i assign a variable for my inner loop, then it updates the value everytime and generates only the last value. Do you have any advice on how to generate 480 dataframes into global environment?

Comment: Are your 480 dataframes saved in a list?